# How do I hide control variables from lm summary

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I am want to use a linear regression model with `y` as my dependent variable and `x1 x2`being my independent variables. Now I also have 2 control variables `z1 z2`. Both of them are indicator variables(SIC codes and a year) saved as factors. Is there a way to not show every level of these indicators in the output? They both have ~20 levels and make the output when using `summary(lm(y~x1+x2+z1+z2))`completely unreadable.

I tried using the `summary.lm` command but when I tried, the output looked like this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = tmd2$eps ~ tmd2$marketcap + tmd2$post + tmd2$year_dummy + 
    tmd2$SIC)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-18.6260  -0.5528   0.0000   0.8117   8.4759 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
Error in symnum(pv, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, cutpoints = c(0, 0.001,  : 'x' must be between 0 and 1
```

Where did I screw up?

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please?  (Your example doesn't need 20 levels in the indicator variable: you could make up some data with `z ~ x1+z1` where `z1` only has a few levels ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`summary` returns a value that you can manipulate before you display. Here is a small example using the iris data.

```
LMI = lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data=iris)
summary(LMI)

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.79424 -0.21874  0.00899  0.20255  0.73103 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        2.17127    0.27979   7.760 1.43e-12 ***
Sepal.Width        0.49589    0.08607   5.761 4.87e-08 ***
Petal.Length       0.82924    0.06853  12.101  < 2e-16 ***
Petal.Width       -0.31516    0.15120  -2.084  0.03889 *  
Speciesversicolor -0.72356    0.24017  -3.013  0.00306 ** 
Speciesvirginica  -1.02350    0.33373  -3.067  0.00258 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3068 on 144 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8673,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8627 
F-statistic: 188.3 on 5 and 144 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now suppose that we want to look at the information about the coefficients, but only for the continuous variables (leaving out the Species corresponds to leaving out your control variables).  Instead of printing the summary directly,  we capture the output and only display the part that we want.

```
SLMI = summary(LMI)
SLMI$coefficients[1:4,]
               Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   2.1712663 0.27979415  7.760227 1.429502e-12
Sepal.Width   0.4958889 0.08606992  5.761466 4.867516e-08
Petal.Length  0.8292439 0.06852765 12.100867 1.073592e-23
Petal.Width  -0.3151552 0.15119575 -2.084418 3.888826e-02
```

We get the reduced output.

Comment: Thank you so much! And how would I include the output below the --- line as well? The R2s etc?

Comment: @Amy, type str(SLMI) to see how the summary is structured, including the names of the different parts.